# how to use QtCharts in my application

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qtcharts

I want to use a `QtChart` in my application and have copied contents of the `linechart` example [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-linechart-example.html)(which compiles and runs fine) into my application mainwindow.cpp's constructor & I added `QT       += charts` into my project's `.pro` file but `QtCreator` now complains: `Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: charts`. How do I fix this?

I'm running this on `Kubuntu 16.04`

Comment: What is your OS? How have you installed Qt? Do you have several versions of Qt? Are you sure you have that module installed?

Comment: make sure that you have installed Qt Charts first

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, I'm running it on `Kubuntu 16.04` and as said, the example compiles & runs fine

Comment: @saeed the example compiles & runs fine, that means the module must be installed already, doesn't it?

Comment: Did you download Qt from the official page or installed it from the Kubuntu repositories?  QtCharts module not enabled by default. Tell me in detail how you installed Qt.

Comment: @eyllanesc is must've been through the official repositories. How can I enable it plus why would the example application compile & work fine?